# How to add selection field for country in information panel

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-website

How do I add a selection field for country in information panel of `product.product_normal_form_view`

[image: Screenshot : I need to add selection field for country in information panel of product.product_normal_form_view as shown in this image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more concise and moved the question in body. I also formatted the image properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit the question to provide any additional detail in order to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```html
<record id="product_normal_form_view_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.normal.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
                <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='Information']/group/group/field[@name='list_price']" position="after">
                     <field name="country_id"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit `product.template`.

Your `xml` file should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="product_template_product_form_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.template.product.form.inherited</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//page[@string='Information']/group/group" position="inside">
                        <field name='country_id'/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

`python` file:

```
from openerp import models, fields


class product_template(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    country_id = fields.Many2one('res.country', 'Country')
```

Comment: Did this answer help you?